# Rotation of table1 rows for given date range based on each employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need one small help in understanding of repeating in cycle the rows from one table (RuleSetting) to my result.

Few points to remember:

1. For now I have only 2 setting value for emplloyee 4536, it could be 4 or 5 as well..
2. SettingId **rotating** after every **7 days** because in RuleSetting Table I have mentioned WeekOffFrequency = 7 for employee **4536**
3. Instead of 99 it should repeat between settingIds 1,2
4. It should work for all employee

SQL Fiddler link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/92011

I have attached the screenshot so that I can explain my requirement more clearly.

**Note:**

1. Records/Rows in RuleSetting table is not fixed... employee can have nth number of settings...
2. but RuleSetting.WeekOffFrequency value will be always same for employee

[image]

**Please ask me if thre is any doubt...**

Comment: It looks like you want to take the blue and grey rows and repeat them each for the number of days given in the rows, then join these repeated rows numerically to the days the employee works.   for example if the blue row was repeated 7 times with a row number 1 - 7 and then the grey row was repeated 7 times with row number 8 - 14, then we could join it to the green rows by doing a day datediff between min date of green rows versus current row to get a number that starts from 1 and goes up to 19, then we could join it MODulo by the max in the repeated numbered rows (modulo 14). Right?

Comment: By doing the datediff day modulo 14 you get a number that cycles from 0-13, Add one to it to get 1-14 cycling just like your blue and grey rows are 1-14. This means when the join occurs each dates row joins to one of the blue or grey rows

Comment: The logic is to keep one setting at a time for every seven days.... And  the settingids should rotate between the dates.... for each employee

Comment: Then what means "weekofffrequency" 14 for employeee 6969? Why is it 14 and not 7?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: @vijaysahu are the values of RotateSettingId for EmployeeId 6969 correct ? or should they be 3 everywhere as we have only settingId 3 available in the table @RuleSettings?

Comment: @sacse.... SettingId will reset to 1 for every employee...

Comment: @vijaysahu ok, so for all records of 6969 should have RotateSettingId as 1, right? as (per the given screenshot)..

Comment: @Caius   It is 14 because this employee settings Will after every 14 days interval... And this value could be anything but divisible of 7 only... For example 7, 14 ,21, 28 and so on...

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks.. for your queries and response... I got my answer but still I am waiting for your answer so that... I can vote for your efforts too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly modified your query and added RuleSettingsModified and NewRotateSettingId.
Please check if that works fine for you.

```
RuleSettingsModified AS
(
    SELECT Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY rs.EmployeeID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn, rs.EmployeeID, rs.WeekOffFrequency
    FROM @RuleSettings rs   
)
```

---

```
(Id / (SELECT DISTINCT WeekOffFrequency FROM @RuleSettings WHERE EmployeeID = ed.EmployeeID))%(SELECT count(1) FROM RuleSettingsModified rsm WHERE rsm.EmployeeID = ed.EmployeeID)+1 AS NewRotateSettingId
```

---

```
;with dates_CTE (RosterDate) as (
    select @sdate 
    Union ALL
    select DATEADD(day, 1, RosterDate)
    from dates_CTE
    where RosterDate < @edate
),
EmployeeDates as (
SELECT  
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by EmployeeId order by RosterDate) - 1 as Id,
EmployeeID,
RosterDate
FROM dates_CTE
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId from  @RuleSettings)as cs
),
RuleSettingsModified AS
(
    SELECT Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY rs.EmployeeID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn, rs.EmployeeID, rs.WeekOffFrequency
    FROM @RuleSettings rs   
)
,
EmployeeWeekOffFrequency as (

    SELECT *, 
    Id / (SELECT DISTINCT WeekOffFrequency from @RuleSettings where EmployeeID = ed.EmployeeID)+ 1  as WeekOffFrequency,
    (
        CASE 
        WHEN 
            ( 
                Id / (SELECT DISTINCT WeekOffFrequency FROM @RuleSettings WHERE EmployeeID = ed.EmployeeID)
            ) 
            < 
            (SELECT count(1) FROM @RuleSettings WHERE EmployeeID = ed.EmployeeID)
        THEN  
        (
            SELECT SettingId FROM @RuleSettings WHERE EmployeeID = ed.EmployeeID 
            AND SettingId = ((Id / (SELECT DISTINCT WeekOffFrequency FROM @RuleSettings  
            WHERE EmployeeID = ed.EmployeeID )) + 1 )
        ) 
        ELSE 99
        END
    ) as RotateSettingId,
    (Id / (SELECT DISTINCT WeekOffFrequency FROM @RuleSettings WHERE EmployeeID = ed.EmployeeID))%(SELECT count(1) FROM RuleSettingsModified rsm WHERE rsm.EmployeeID = ed.EmployeeID)+1 AS NewRotateSettingId
    from EmployeeDates as ed 
)
SELECT * FROM EmployeeWeekOffFrequency
```

Please see complete code **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=162bf9fcae634a0592c97f0b8bee34bb)**.

Comment: You should copy th complete code into your answer; this answer becomes relatively meaningless if the fiddle is lost

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the complete code. Life doesn't work in 'ifs and buts...' (just saying :)).

Comment: Yes its working perfect your new column did all the work.... but I have one question do we really need RuleSettingsModified  , because it return the same what RuleSetting does...

Comment: and also I liked your approach.. you first politely asked all your queries took your time and then you wrote your answer.. it's very appreciable (Y)

Comment: It's 3 for 6969 in the screenshot (ideally it should be 1). If the numbers are already corrected in RuleSettings then there is no use of a modified version. Always happy to help. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented it as follows.
[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0f46ca2fd7f494a068a21e13fc1878f)

1. ExpandRuleSettings(add): Expand rows of RuleSettings to number of WeekOffFrequency each SettingId of employee.
2. NumberOfRotate(add): Get number of rotate (number of all SettingId of each employee).
3. EmployeeDates(change): Allocate rotated Id for date each employee.
4. EmployeeWeekOffFrequency(change): Join the tables EmployeeDates and ExpandRuleSettings on matching EmployeeID and Id.

```
DECLARE @sdate date = '2020-09-10', @edate date = '2020-09-28'

;with dates_CTE (RosterDate) as (
    select @sdate 
    Union ALL
    select DATEADD(day, 1, RosterDate)
    from dates_CTE
    where RosterDate < @edate
),

-- Expand rows of RuleSettings to number of WeekOffFrequency each SettingId of employee.
ExpandRuleSettingsWork as (
  SELECT 0 AS IdForSettingId, SettingId, EmployeeID, ShiftPattern, WeekOffFrequency FROM @RuleSettings
  UNION ALL
  SELECT IdForSettingId+1, SettingId, EmployeeID, ShiftPattern, WeekOffFrequency FROM ExpandRuleSettingsWork
  WHERE IdForSettingId+1 < WeekOffFrequency
),
ExpandRuleSettings as (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY SettingId,IdForSettingId)-1 AS Id,
    * FROM ExpandRuleSettingsWork
),
-- SELECT * FROM ExpandRuleSettings ORDER BY EmployeeID,SettingId,Id

-- Get number of rotate (number of all SettingId of each employee).
NumberOfRotate as (
  SELECT EmployeeID, COUNT(EmployeeID) AS Num FROM ExpandRuleSettings GROUP BY EmployeeID
),
-- SELECT * FROM NumberOfRotate

EmployeeDates as (
SELECT  
(ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by EmployeeId order by RosterDate) - 1) % Num as Id,
EmployeeID,
RosterDate
FROM dates_CTE
CROSS APPLY NumberOfRotate
)

--select * from EmployeeDates
--order by EmployeeID , RosterDate


,
EmployeeWeekOffFrequency as (
  SELECT ed.*, er.SettingId
  FROM EmployeeDates as ed INNER JOIN ExpandRuleSettings as er
  ON ed.EmployeeID=er.EmployeeID AND 
    ed.Id = er.Id
)

SELECT * FROM EmployeeWeekOffFrequency
```

Comment: @etsuhia Yes it's working as expected. Thanks for your answer..